# Synchronizing ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, synchronization

In `ArrayList` api we have:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the
>   threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized
>   externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or
>   deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array;
>   merely setting the value of an element is not a structural
>   modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some
>   object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists,
>   the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList
>   method.

Here what is meant by "This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list"? How this related to concurrent modification exception?

Comment: If you synchronize access to the object you won't get a CME.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the
>   list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList
>   method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental
>   unsynchronized access to the list:
>
> ```
>    List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
> ```

By "naturally encapsulates" it means that if the list is a field of an object, but the list is not publically accessible suppose the following:

```
class ParkingLot{
   private ArrayList<Cars> spots;

   public boolean park(int spotNumber, Car car){          
       if( spots.get(spotNumber)==null){
            spot.set(spotNumber,car);
            return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
}
```

In this case `ParkinLot` would encapulate the list `spot`. If you were to try and call `park()`, you'd want to synchronize on the `ParkingLot` object to prevent two threads trying to park a car in the same spot at the same time.

It is related to a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) in that it prevents you from changing the list from separate threads simultaneously (by synchronizing), which could leave the list in an inconsistent state (ie Two cars parking at the same time thinking they've successfully parked).

Answer (score 1):

> Here what is meant by "This is typically accomplished by synchronizing
>   on some object that naturally encapsulates the list"

If you have a class which encapsulates an `ArrayList` then if you synchronize on the wrapper object than the underlying `ArrayList` will also be `synchronized`. e.g.

```
class MyClasss{

      private final ArrayList list;
      ......
      ......
      ......
 }
```

If you synchronize on the instance of MyClass than the underlying list is also synchronized and the all the read / write will be serialized e.g.

```
class MyClasss{

      private final ArrayList list;
      ......
      ......
      ......
      public void fun(){
          synchronized(this){
                list.add(....)
           }
 }
```

---

> How this related to concurrent modification exception?
>   Before answering the above question you need to understand how `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown by JVM.

`ConcurrentModificationException` is implemented in java by checking the modification count of each `Collection`. Every time you do an operation it compares the modification count before doing the operation and after doing the operation.

So if you `synchronize` the `Collection` then simultaneous modification of the modification count will not happen resulting in not throwing the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: As the access to modCount is not synchronized a ConcurrentModificationException  might not even be thrown if you access the arraylist from many threads without synchronization

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) instead? It's already synchronized.

Comment: `Vector` is depreciated see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated